# GLFW_INVALID_ENUM error, while creating display in lwjgl

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am trying to make a game in java. I am following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/a4Xwp2ln-N0. When you launch app, window must appear with nothing in it, but when i try to launch it, this error shows up:

```
[LWJGL] GLFW_INVALID_ENUM error
    Description : Invalid OpenGL profile 0x00022008
    Stacktrace  :
        org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1714)
        org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1897)
        core.WindowManager.init(WindowManager.java:61)
        Launching.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:12)
```

Here is line 61 in WindowManager: `window =  GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(width,height,title, MemoryUtil.NULL,MemoryUtil.NULL);` and line 12 in launcher: `window.init();` Thanks!

Comment: Which window flags did you set? Please show the exact code you are executing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems was with one line:
`GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE);`
Thanks BDL for insipiring me to test flags!